# Plotting a list of numbers over a range of numbers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
        Season      Dist
0   '14 - '15       [120, 128, 175, 474, 615]
1   '15 - '16       [51, 305, 398, 839, 991, 1093, 1304]
2   '16 - '17       [223, 293, 404, 588, 661, 706, 964, 1049, 1206]
3   '17 - '18       [12, 37, 204, 229, 276, 349, 809, 845, 1072, 1...
4   '18 - '19       [210, 214, 259, 383, 652, 798, 1150]
5   '19 - '20       [182, 206, 221, 282, 283, 297, 1330, 1332]
```

I'm trying to plot it with matplotlib where the x axis is the range of instances and for each season on the y axis, the plot shows the distribution of the `df['Dist']`. I've sketched a very crappy graph below to illustrate my point. [image]

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: something like this https://imgur.com/O6OF3PF ? I only plotted two seasons

Comment: Have a go yourself first.  Then show your code if you can't get it to do what you want.   There are some really simple examples to get you going in the [matplotlib documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html)

Comment: @Julkar9 yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! How did you do that?

Comment: @Bill I tried doing something like this `plt.plot(list(df['Dist']), list(df['Season']))
plt.axis([0, 1500])
plt.show()` but that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plot each list individually on the same graph. The list values will work as x-coordinates, so for y-coordinates map each season values to ints. i.e something like this

```
        Season      Dist
0        0       [120, 128, 175, 474, 615]
1        1       [51, 305, 398, 839, 991, 1093, 1304]
2   '    2       [223, 293, 404, 588, 661, 706, 964, 1049, 1206]
```

Now scatterplot will require y-coordinates for every x-coordinate.
So create something like this

```
    y                      x
[0,0,0,0,0]           [120, 128, 175, 474, 615]
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]       [51, 305, 398, 839, 991, 1093, 1304]  

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season':['14 - 15','15 - 16','16 - 17'],'Dist':\
                   [[120, 128, 175, 474, 615],\
                    [51, 305, 398, 839, 991, 1093, 1304],\
                    [223, 293, 404, 588, 661, 706, 964, 1049, 1206]]})

y = np.arange(len(df)) #map the seasons

for i in range(len(df)):
    plt.scatter(df['Dist'][i],[y[i] for j in range(len(df['Dist'][i]))]) #create a list of y coordinates for every x coordinate
plt.yticks(y,df['Season']) #show the actual seasons as xticks
plt.show()
```

[image]